# Deleting large chunks of data

Tags: sql-server

```
    create table Grid(
    grid_id,
    //other columns
    )
    //grid_id is primary key

    create table grid_info(
    grid_id,
    colulm_id,
    column_vale
    )
    //grid_id is foreign key to grid_id of table Gird

// These is around 10 million    
select grid_id from grid into #temp where //some logic

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_temp_id ON #temp(grid_id)

    set rowcount 10000
                    while 1 = 1
                    begin 
                        delete from grid_info where grid_id in (select grid_id from #temp)
                        if @@rowcount = 0
                        break
                    end
                    set rowcount 0
```

This batch is slow because of large number of rows to be deleted. What are the things to be considered to make things faster. Like how the indexing,triggers plays a role and how can you test the performance of your queries using what kind tools?

Comment: There are a ton of things that can be considered, and I am not to sure your question can be really be answered. In the sense that each person has their own preferences on what tools and methods they use to test. As well, do you want tools that are free, built-in to SQL Server, or that you have to pay for but give you more readable results?

Comment: Once the 10 million rows are in the #temp table, and after you perform the delete, what do you do with them?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding performance testing:

The SQL Server Management Studio includes some performance measurement capabilities:  When executing your query, select the 'Include Actual Execution Plan' to see the steps involved in executing your query, the method used for achieving each step, the indexes and tables used, and the size of the result set.

If you are using SQL Server Standard or better:

- The SQL Server Management Studio will provide recommendations for improving performance.
- You may also use the SQL Server Profiler to measure the read, writes and CPU time for your procedure.
- You may also use the Data Engine Tuning Advisor to see further recommendations.

I  recommend this book: [SQL Server 2008 Query Performance Tuning Distilled](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430219025)